# How do I get ready for my first dog?

Tags: dogs, adoption

A good friend of mine is getting very sick (kidney disease. :( ) and is having to give up his dogs, including a 1 year old Cheweenie mix named Titan that I'm adopting, initially out of guilt but he's just plain grown on me.  I am really, really attached to the dog and am getting ready to bring him home.

Currently, Titan is left at home most of the day with four other dogs (his mom and siblings), and when i bring him home, he'll be alone most of the day alone.  I know there's a nearby dog daycare that I could take him to a few times a week (I've seen a few questions about folks that are in similar situations that suggested this), and I can commit to the time to take him for walks, since i'm planning on doing more active stuff as it is.

I've lived with dogs, but I've never had one before. I read [This question about getting ready for dogsitting](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11259/what-steps-should-i-take-to-prepare-myself-for-dogsitting) and it answered a few questions, but **what other things should I do to prepare my apartment to make sure Titan is comfortable?  What should the first week or so look like as I get Titan settled into his new home?**

A few things about Titan:

- As I mentioned, Titan is used to having his brothers and sisters around constantly.  I don't know what to do for the poor guy about this.
- He's a digger, and destroyed a couch already.  I just got a new one, so... yay.
- He's a small dog, so is there a good time or distance for a morning walk for him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His current owner should pass on his basic dog gear:

- Leash, collar, and harness
- Crate
- Dog food (you should continue feeding Titan whatever his current owner is, at least for the short term)
- Treats
- Toys

You should plan to take a few days off work to allow Titan to acclimate to his new home.  During this time you can get him used to your schedule, the new surroundings, and so on.  You can also ease him into being alone for longer periods of time (hang out together for the first day and then leave for 30 minutes the next, an hour the day after that, and so on).

Daycare is a great option for many dogs, though even if Titan is regularly going to daycare when you're at work you'll want him to be ok being alone for several hours at a time.  This way if you want to see a movie with friends or go out to dinner you know he'll be ok hanging out on his own.

Since Titan likes digging, or maybe digs when he's bored, you'll want to make sure you have lots for him to do.  Chiweenie's are high energy dogs, so if his current owner doesn't provide him with lots of puzzle toys, playtime, and training you'll benefit from doing these things.

Even though Titan is a small dog, he'll need a good amount of exercise.  If there's a dog run or off leash park nearby you should plan to bring him there on his morning walks - this way he'll be less destructive/bored during the day if he's home alone.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll have to get up earlier for sure. My complex provides parks for large and small dogs, so I'll be sure to take him there. Otherwise, my mom has two dogs and has offered to take him a day or two a week so he has friends to play with. Any good examples of puzzle toys?

Comment: @AdamWells that's awesome that your mom has dogs he can play with (and also that your apartment complex has dog runs - I'm jealous).  For puzzle/interactive toys I love anything Kong brand - I use those for all my dogs meals.  I also like the Starmark Wobbler and anything Outward Hound makes as well.